# How do I compile a uxl-file from Dart-Editor?

Tags: dart, rikulo

I installed the dependencies from this tutorial http://docs.rikulo.org/rikulo/latest/UXL/Fundamentals/UXL_Overview.html

```yaml
dependencies:
  rikulo_uxl:
    git: git://github.com/rikulo/uxl.git
```

trying to compile with uc.dart
I get:

```
Error: line 8 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:args/args.dart';
```

what is wrong? missing path?

Comment: Did you run Tools -> Pub Install on the project? Maybe the args package hasn't been installed locally yet.

Comment: I have had some success with the ScrollViewDemo working with the Dat Editor (beta) 1.3.  See: [Wanted: Rikulo UXL example(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608569/wanted-rikulo-uxl-examples)

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when you reference a package that isn't found on disk. You should ensure you have [the package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/args) listed in your `pubspec.yaml` and that you've run `pub get`. You can also check that inside your `packages` folder you can see a folder named `args`.