# Wanted: Rikulo UXL example(s)

Tags: dart, markup, rikulo

I want to get some UXL working with the Dart Editor.  I'm afraid that I feel the sample code on [UXL Overview](http://docs.rikulo.org/ui/latest/UXL/Fundamentals/UXL_Overview.html) is either out of date or lacks some critical steps to let it perform.  (See also: [What is Rikulo dart really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477972/what-is-rikulo-dart-really), which directs people to the blogs).

I want to get up to speed with something like the UXL mark-up for the Dart environment.  So are the only examples I've found are on the blog/documentation and the seem to be incomplete.

- https://github.com/rikulo/uxl

And it seems like it may not be '*just me*' I find the examples confusing.  Is a UXL mark-up a 'abc.UXL' or 'abc.uxl.XML' file?  For now I'm looking at Rikulo because I see it as the *kind of* extremely helpful framework I like to see.

That said, please [rikulo](/questions/tagged/rikulo) people, provide three or four examples that work with a few tweaks and a bit of thought.

I'll put that same thing out there for others wanting doing tools and frameworks.  **Examples teach**.  And make sure your examples always work.  Make them part of your unit testing.

Cheers, Will.

Comment: I can report a minor step forward in my quest.  I took the UXL master from github and made a project from the example called, "ScrollView".  It did **not** run at first.  After a Dart Editor upgrade to 1.3.0-dev_06_01 (Dart SDK v1.3.0-dev.6.1) a scrolling grid appeared.  OK progress.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, all samples in [the document](http://docs.rikulo.org/ui/latest/UXL/Fundamentals/UXL_Overview.html) shall work fine. If we changed spec, we will update the document accordingly.

You can name it `.uxl` or `.uxl.xml`, but I'd suggest `.uxl.xml` if your editor supports XML. Otherwise, you have to configure it to recognize `.xul`.

> Not sure what *critical steps* you mean or expect. Better to provide a more specific question.

---

### A helpful example [ed. Will] ...

I made a small addition to the ScrollView example that is saved on GitHub for the UXL project.

### ScrollView.uxl.xml

```
<!-- ScrollViewTemplate -->
<?dart
part of ScrollViewDemo;
?>

<Template name="ScrollViewTemplate" args="rows: 30, cols: 30">
  <ScrollView class="scroll-view"
  profile="location: center center; width: 80%; height: 80%">
    <Apply forEach="r = 0; r < rows; ++r">
      <Apply forEach="c = 0; c < cols; ++c">
        <View style="border: 1px solid #553; 
              background-color: ${CssUtil.color(250 - r * 4, 250 - c * 4, 200)}"
              left="${r * 50 + 2}" top="${c * 50 + 2}"
              width="${46}" height="${46}">
         ( ${r}, ${c} )
        </View>
      </Apply>
    </Apply>
  </ScrollView>
</Template>
```

### build.dart

```
//import 'package:polymer/builder.dart';
import 'package:rikulo_uxl/uc.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
    build( args );
}
```

What makes this different from the GitHub example?

1. This includes the **build**.dart file
2. Each cell shows its coordinates.  That shows two things.

   - How to use UXL values *inside* the UXL mark-up and
   - In the runtime it shows you how the scrolling works with the cells
3. This demo runs on Dart Editor download

   - Dart Editor version 1.3.0.dev_06_01 (DEV)
   - Dart SDK version 1.3.0-dev.6.1
   - The sample didn't work with the 6.0 version

I would also point out that for me, it seems unusual to need to download the UXL project to find one demo.  And I need to clarify what a 'demo' might be to "me" as the code I downloaded wasn't an example of anything it just demonstrated one or three UXL features.

I understand people are busy and stuff.  And still, in my opinion testing, integration, documentation and examples make 80% of a project the other 20% being code.  Others have different opinions.  (*I think the proportions will be congruent if you have done this for more than 5 years though. Just guessing.*)

Comment: Hi, thanks for a response.  If the information about file name extensions documented I totally missed it.  It seems my Dart Editor may be to blame but.  At least it compiles now with 1.30-dev_06_01 (see above).

Comment: Small details aside; I would point out that to me, an ***example*** is something that demonstrates a reasonable Use Case and shows (educates one on) how to do something.  Showing the use of certain functionality.  If one is looking for examples to demonstrate a framework or language, I recommend a look-see at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) there are several common programming tasks for people compare implementations in different languages/frameworks.   Also for *completeness*, to me a 'sample' is a mini-application.  Very simple functionality to show how-to.